# sum of elements but skip one element in each iteration in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

skip one element of array   in each iteration while doing a sum of array  in python , for example if I have a array `[0,2,3,5,6,5,8,9]` how can I do sum for first 7 element then on next iteration sum of the rest array except first element

```
for x in range(len(arr)):
   maxi = max(sum(arr), maximum)

   return maxi
```

this return the sum of the whole array but I want to skip one element in each iteration and then skip the other element but add the previous element that was skipped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sum the array once then subtract one element at a time:

```
li = [0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 5, 8, 9]
array_sum = sum(li)

for n in li:
    print('sum of array is', array_sum, ', without', n, 'the sum is', array_sum - n)
```

outputs

```
sum of array is 38 , without 0 the sum is 38
sum of array is 38 , without 2 the sum is 36
sum of array is 38 , without 3 the sum is 35
sum of array is 38 , without 5 the sum is 33
sum of array is 38 , without 6 the sum is 32
sum of array is 38 , without 5 the sum is 33
sum of array is 38 , without 8 the sum is 30
sum of array is 38 , without 9 the sum is 29
```

If you are only interested in the max sum:

```
li = [0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 5, 8, 9]
print(max(sum(li) - n for n in li))
```

At this point, you don't even need the loop. By definition, we'll get the max sum when substructing the smallest element.

```
print(sum(li) - min(li))
```

Comment: what if I want to take maximum sum of this array ? should I try max function ? I tried but didn't work but thanks for this code

Comment: @AbdulBasitNiazi you can either store all the sums in a list then use the `max` function or find the max sum as you go

Comment: Thank you very much @Deepspace